# UI-select Focus remains

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ui-select

I am using ui-select (Version: 0.8.3, angularjs) library in order to display a drop down list.

I have a situation when i click on a text area there is JavaScript that changes the height of the div to a larger height so it can be scrolled up.
the problem is that when it occures the dropdown remains open and does not close.

after a little of debugging i saw that the OnDocumentClick is not being called once the height is to big.

if i don't change the height of the div, it is working correctly.

Is there any other solution possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NsN3t90Tr3YzKmpRMcue?p=preview

when u click here on the text box the hieght of the dice is increased but if before the click the dropdown was opened then it remains open and does not close.

Comment: Which browser are you using?  In chrome the div height increases when clicking either textbox, but the dropdowns only stay open if you click a textbox in the other div (ie: top dropdown stays open on click of bottom textbox).  Seems like some event handling isn't happening correctly.

Comment: i am using chrome, i need the dropdown to close every time it loses control.